# How to remove comma at the end of a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, string-formatting, pokeapi

I'm working with an library called pokebase in Python which is a wrapper for Pokeapi.

**Code:**

```
import pokebase as pb #pip install pokebase
p1 = pb.pokemon('venusaur')
types = ''
for poketype in p1.types:
    types += poketype.type.name.capitalize()+', '
print(types)
```

It prints the data like this:

```
Grass, Poison,
```

So I learned how to use this API on a YouTube tutorial, but the problem here is that when i run the `for` loop it prints ', ' at the end of output also which is grammatically wrong. How can I fix that?
I have tried to remove it using `end` and `separator` parameters to `print()` but it doesn't work. How can I remove the comma at the end?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do:

```
types = ','.join(poketype.type.name.capitalize() for poketype in p1.types)
```

`.join()` function takes an iterable and joins its elements.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably just use `join()` here, as that would be very straightforward.  If you did really want to stick your loop approach, then you need to rephrase the logic such that the final comma does not get appended.  In that case, I'd go with:

```py
types = ''
for poketype in p1.types:
    if types != '':
        types += ', '
    types += poketype.type.name.capitalize()
print(types)
```

The above logic says to prepend a comma in front of each term, starting from the second term onwards.  This avoids every placing a dangling comma after the final term.

Answer (score 1):

Other option if you want to stick to loop option. You can change the last print statement to

```
print(types[:-2])
```

It will remove the last 2 chars.